# Return Values from AngularJS services

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, service, return

I am trying to return a value from my AngularJs service to my controller where ever I pass it inside the controller.It does pass the object and also log the data in the console. Here is my code:

```
angular.module('demoService',[])
.factory('myService',
function($http) {
return {
    getAll: function (items) {
        var path = "http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census"
        $http.get(path).success(function (items) {

        console.log(items.Tweets[1].FAVOURITE_COUNT);

       });
    }
}
});
```

How do i return the "items.Tweets[1].FAVOURITE_COUNT" on function call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a promise of the data queried, by using the method `then` , `getAll` will know what to do before the response of the API.

```
angular.module('demoService')
.factory('myService', ['$http', 
    function ($http) {

        function getAll (items) {
            var path = "http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census"
            return $http.get(path).then(
                function (res) {
                    return res;
                 });
        }

        return {
            getAll: getAll;
        }

    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a promise and resolve it when the request is success. Do not forget to reject it otherwise.

```
angular.module('demoService',[])
.factory('myService',
function($q, $http) {
return {
    getAll: function (items) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var path = "http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census"
        $http.get(path).success(function (items) {

          defer.resolve(items.Tweets[1].FAVOURITE_COUNT);
          console.log(items.Tweets[1].FAVOURITE_COUNT);

       });

       return defer.promise;
    }
}
});
```

Or you could return the promise from $http.get:

```
 return $http.get(path);
```

As the method is call getAll